# Site redirects to dashboard after install

Tags: magento2.3, localhost

I am trying to install Magento in local, I am on my last step but upon viewing the url it redirects to dashboard.

[image]

Comment: Did you install Magento using web setup wizard?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the issue might be inside below file:

```
Xampp7.4\apache\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf
```

Also follow below URL reference for the installation:

```
https://www.thecoachsmb.com/6-steps-to-install-magento2-4-2-on-xampp-windows-using-composer/
```

Thanks.